# C program ignoring if statement containing sizeof

Tags: c, file, if-statement, sizeof

I am currently writing a simple little One-time pad program. I want it to warn the user when the `keyfile` is smaller than the `source` file, but when I run it my program simply ignores it.

```
/* Check if keyfile is the same size as, or bigger than the sourcefile */
if(sizeof keyfile < sizeof sourcefile)
{
printf("Source file is larger than keyfile.\n");
printf("This significantly reduces cryptographic strength.\n");
printf("Do you wish to continue? (Y/N)\n");
scanf("%c", &ans);
if(ans == 'n' || ans == 'N')
    {
    return (1);
    }
if(ans == 'y' || ans == 'Y')
    {
    printf("Proceeding with Encryption/Decryption.\n");
    }
```

I suspect the problem lies with my use `sizeof`, but I don't know about any other options? Any suggestions as to how I can alter my code to make it work?

EDIT: I have tried adding `fstat` to the best of my abilities, but it still reacts in the same manner... here is what I did:

```
/* Get size of sourcefile. */
if((sourcefile = fopen(argv[1], "rb"))== NULL)
{
printf("Can't open source file.\n");
printf("Please enter a valid filename.\n");
printf("USAGE: OTP <source file> <output file> <keyfile>\n");
return (1);
}

fflush(sourcefile);
fstat(fileno(sourcefile), &statbuf);
fclose(sourcefile);

/* Get size of keyfile. */
if((keyfile = fopen(argv[3], "rb"))== NULL)
{
printf("Can't open keyfile.\n");
printf("Please enter a valid filename.\n"); 
printf("USAGE: OTP <source file> <output file> <keyfile>\n");
return(1);

fflush(keyfile);
fstat(fileno(keyfile), &keybuf);
fclose(keyfile);
}
```

and altered the first line of the if statement being ignored:

```
if((keybuf.st_size) < (statbuf.st_size))
```

Why is it still being ignored by the program?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/238603/how-can-i-get-a-files-size-in-c

Comment: Since the decision is made at compile time, showing the correct declarations for the variables `keyfile` and `sourcefile` probably won't matter, but for completeness, you should do that.

Comment: Considere creating another question if you want people to see it, and for the sake of readability.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`sizeof` does not return the size of a file. `sizeof` is use to check the number of bytes a type takes in memory.

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8813136/function-that-returns-file-size) post if you want more information on getting a file's size.

Answer (score 5):

`sizeof` is a compile-time operator yielding the size of its operands' data type in bytes. Are you sure that's what you want to do here? I very much doubt that, as it seems you want to compare *file sizes*. (`fopen()`, `fseek()` to end, `ftell()` to get the size of the file, or whatever more comfortable function your OS' API provides you with.)

Answer (score 4):

`sizeof` is a unary operator used to calculate the size of a datatype. You cannot use it to find/compare the size of text files.

Answer (score 3):

You need to use [stat](http://linux.die.net/man/2/stat) to get the size of a file.

Comment: How to get the file size depends on the platform, of course...that's why it isn't covered by the C standard.  For POSIX-ish systems, `stat` is correct.  For other platforms, the answer varies by platform.

Comment: @DevSolar - True if Windows. But Windows does support POSIX - and stat is POSIX. Just makes it easier to port as well to UNIX (as well as a few other Operating systems)